# jquery checkbox checked toggle when click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I want to toggle the checkbox on click of button.

Here is my jQuery

```
$("#choose_address2").on("click", function () { 
   console.log("click!!! address2");
   var $checkbox = $(this).find(':checkbox');
   var checkBoxes = $("input[name=checkbox]]");
   checkBoxes.prop("checked", !checkBoxes.prop("checked"));
});
```

Here is my Input

```
<span id="choose_address2" class="btn btn-info">
<i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>เพิ่มที่อยู่
<input type="checkbox" name="choose_address" {{#if customer.addresses}}checked{{/if}} id="choose_address1" hidden>
</input></span>
```

By default the button is checked.
however when i click the span with id `choose_address2` I want to change the state. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: try this: $checkbox.prop("checked", !$checkbox.prop("checked"));

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try This

```
$("#choose_address2").on("click", function () { 
   console.log("click!!! address2");
   var $checkbox = $(this).find(':checkbox');
   var checkBoxes = $("input[type='checkbox']");
   if(checkBoxes.prop("checked")==true)
     checkBoxes.prop("checked", false); 
   else
     checkBoxes.prop("checked", true)
});
```

Or This also work

```
$("#choose_address2").on("click", function () { 
   console.log("click!!! address2");
   var $checkbox = $(this).find(':checkbox');
   var checkBoxes = $("input[type='checkbox']");
   (checkBoxes.prop("checked")==true)?checkBoxes.prop("checked", false):checkBoxes.prop("checked", true);       

});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#choose_address2").on("click", function() {
     var $checkbox = $(this).find(':checkbox');
     $checkbox.prop("checked", !$checkbox.prop("checked"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres an example

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="toggle" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
<button id="choose_address2">
 Toggle checkbox
</button>
```

**JQ**

```
$('#choose_address2').click(function(){
   $('.toggle').each(function(){
     $(this).prop('checked', !$(this)[0].checked);
  })
})
```

Demo
http://jsfiddle.net/mPstq/94/

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to tackle this:

```
$checkbox.prop( 'checked', ! $checkbox.is( ':checked' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for you suggestion..

This did the trick for me :

```
$("#choose_address2").click(function(){
   var checkBox = $("#choose_address1");
   console.log("click!!! address2");
   checkBox.trigger('click');
});
```